# How to make table, as the picture show?

Tags: tables, diagrams

How to make table, as the picture show?
Help me pls...

[image]

13/06 [Update]

until now i've got is:

```
\tcbsidebyside[
bicolor,
colframe=black,
colback=blue!30!white,
colbacklower=blue!30!white,
center,
width=7.2cm,
%title=The Triangle,
%fonttitle=\bfseries,center title,
sidebyside adapt=left, % Orientación.
sidebyside gap=1cm, % Distancia entre columnas.
%drop lifted shadow,
drop fuzzy shadow,
arc=3mm
]
{
\tcbox[tikznode]{Secure\\Channel}
%\tcbox[tikznode]{Flow\\Table}
}
{
\tcbox[tikznode]{Group\\Table}
%\tcbox[tikznode]{Flow\\Table}
}
```

[image]

thx user cfr by your comment. someone have idea to make second row?

Comment: Tikz, pstricks .... inkscape....however, it looks like generated with `tcolorbox`

Comment: Thx by comment, i will investigate more about tcolorbox ;)

Comment: Perhaps you need `TikZ` in addition to `tcolorbox`

Comment: If you need a blurry rectangular shadow, you need that blur library thing rather than the `shadows` library. (Unless `tcolorbox` does this. It does most things.)

Comment: You could use ipe and do this in few minutes. ipe allows Latex to be added directly on a drawing.

Comment: Thx by comment cfr y nasser, i will consider it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `tcolorbox` is the best option for drawing your scheme.

Here is a pure Ti*k*Z solution.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={
            text width=4em,
            align=center,
            draw,
            thick,
            fill=gray!40,
            inner sep=10pt,
            }
}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Large]
    \matrix[
        column sep=5em,
        row sep=7ex,
        thick,
        draw,
        fill=cyan!40,
        matrix of nodes,
        inner sep=24pt,
        nodes={
            mynode,
            anchor=west,
            },
        blur shadow
        ] (mymatr) {
            |[text width=7.5em]|{Secure\\ Channel} &
            {Group\\ table}\\
            {Flow\\ table} &
            {Flow\\ table}\\
            };
    \node[above=16ex of mymatr-1-1, mynode, text width=7.5em, font=\bfseries\Large, blur shadow](contr){Controller};
    \draw[Triangle-Triangle, dashed, very thick] (contr) -- (mymatr-1-1) node[midway, above, fill=white, font=\bfseries\Large]{OpenFlow Protocol};
    \coordinate (m) at ($(mymatr-1-1.east)!.5!(mymatr-1-2.west)$);
    \draw[dashed, thick] (mymatr.west) -| (mymatr.north -| m);
    \coordinate (a) at ($(mymatr-2-1.east)!.33!(mymatr-2-2.west)$);
    \coordinate (b) at ($(mymatr-2-1.east)!.66!(mymatr-2-2.west)$);
    \draw[-Stealth, very thick] (mymatr-2-1.east) -- (a);
    \draw[dashed, very thick] (a) -- (b) node[midway, below=20pt]{PipeLine};
    \draw[-Stealth, very thick] (b) -- (mymatr-2-2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]